# Why does `@babel/transform-runtime` not polyfill `string.replace` for Edge 18?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, microsoft-edge, babel-polyfill

From the Babel docs, it seems I can polyfill my code using either `@babel/preset-env` or `@babel/transform-runtime` in my babel config file.

`@babel/preset-env` with `useBuiltIns: usage` will add a polyfill for `string.replace` when my targeted list of browsers includes Edge 18.

Using `@babel/transform-runtime` instead, `string.replace` seems not to be polyfilled.

I'd like to use both, but the [docs recommend not to](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#babelruntime):

[image]

Should I use `@babel/preset-env` ? Or is `@babel/runtime` more up-to-date and therefore doesn't bring in `string.replace` polyfill?

Comment: String.prototype.replace() has been around for an eternity. Can't imagine ever needing a polyfill for it

Comment: @charlietfl It's probably about the new regex features that a `replace` call would need to consider. Existence of the method alone doesn't help :-)

Comment: @Bergi ah, yes, that could be it. And since `@babel/transform-runtime` doesn't bring in that polyfill, would it be considered best practice to use `@babel/preset-env` to polyfill instance methods - and then to use `@babel/transform-runtime` for its original purpose of injecting calls to a babel helper runtime instead of babel writing those helpers directly into transpiled files?

Comment: Why do you think it should polyfill `string.replace`? Maybe you are confusing with `replaceAll` which does require a polyfill for Edge.